# Coefficient of Determination - Exceeding 1.

Tags: statistics

To understand this concept (Coefficient of Determination) I just assumed a set of values and tried to find its Coefficient of Determination $R^2$. The problem I faced was that the value was around 4. (I've always assumed that the value is going to be between 0 and 1.) The set of values were $x_1 = $ {$1,2,3,4$} ,  $x_2 = $ {$3,4,1,3$} and $y = $ {$5,7,9,11$}.

I used $ y = a + bx_1 + cx_2 $. Then I multiplied this equation by coefficients of the unknowns ($1,x_1,x_2$) to get three equations and summed those up. Then I solved them simultaneously to find the unknowns ($a,b,c$). Then I found $R^2$ which came out to be about 4.

Now my question is can $R^2$ exceed 1 and if it can what can I infer about the data when $R^2$ goes beyond 1.

Comment: Procedure not clear to me, so I can't check it.